# Do we need a canonical answer to "I got my degree but then I interviewed and the questions were too hard."?

Tags: discussion

We see lots of questions both here and on [Programmer's](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) along the lines of

"I graduated and went on an interview and they asked questions I couldn't answer. Was I really supposed to be learning that stuff? No one told me. It's not fair. I have my diploma and someone owes me a job."

Seems to be the Dunning-Kreuger effect in action. The graduate didn't really learn the material and doesn't understand that some students mastered it.

Most of these questions are closed as "not a real question" or "primarily opinion-based" but they keep coming.

Is there somewhere we can write the canonical answer to these questions?

Comment: I'm not sure this would be the best site for the canonical answer itself.  Perhaps the question could be asked here as CW, but linked and locked to the canonical Programmers.SE question. … On second thought, I suppose it depends on how general you want the question/answer to be.

Answer (score -3):

I hear you, but I wouldn't really worry about it or lose any sleep over it.

Merry Christmas!

Comment: +0, but this really would be better as a comment…

Comment: @SeanAllred Meta sites work differently, though. On a main site, this should almost certainly have been a comment. Here, it's a legitimate "I don't think what's described in the question is a problem" type of answer.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling perhaps here, this is the case. Vote count would show evidence to the contrary, though. (Again, +0)

Comment: @SeanAllred Not really. Meta site voting, particularly on [discussion] questions, can just as easily indicate agreement or disagreement with the point made. So the fact that a few people have downvoted this may just mean that a few people disagree with the point made.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling This is true in part -- trust me that I'm aware of how the model works :P For truly negligent answers though, `-1` will often be a note that the answer needs work. On Meta, it would note that the opinion needs to be expanded on or backed up.